# Having trouble understanding a reflection test in Javascript Koans

Tags: javascript, reflection

There is already an answer posted to the test itself, which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807005/javascript-koans-cannot-solve-one-test), but I can't seem to figure out **why** that answer is correct.

The part of the [test](https://github.com/liammclennan/JavaScript-Koans/blob/master/topics/about_reflection.js) that is giving me trouble is:

```
var keys = [];
var fruits =  ['apple', 'orange'];
for(propertyName in fruits) {
    keys.push(propertyName);
}
ok(keys.equalTo(['__', '__', '__']), 'what are the properties of the array?');
```

The (apparently) correct answer, as noted in the above linked question is

```
ok(keys.equalTo(['0', '1', 'fruits.prototype'), 'what are the properties of the array?');
```

I tried inserting the answer - fixed the syntax error - and my test still fails.

In the same test file, another test is nearly identical and the answer is what I would expect it to be:

```
test("property enumeration", function() {
    var keys = [];
    var values = [];
    var person = {name: 'Amory Blaine', age: 102, unemployed: true};
    for(propertyName in person) {
        keys.push(propertyName);
        values.push(person[propertyName]);
    }
    ok(keys.equalTo(['name','age','unemployed']), 'what are the property names of the object?');
    ok(values.equalTo(['Amory Blaine',102,true]), 'what are the property values of the object?');
});
```

The only difference I can see between these two tests is that the second is using an object rather than an array.

I ran the code from the first test by itself (outside of the unit testing framework) and output the value of keys, which it showed as `["0","1"]` - what I would expect. Where is this hidden third value, and how can I access it?

So, I guess I ultimately have two questions:

1. Why is the answer from the other question not working for me?
2. What is different about the first test and the second test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm pretty sure this is right, but haven't bothered testing it. Could you try my answer out, since you've got the tests running?

Looking at the files on GitHub, there is a helper script called [`koan.js`](https://github.com/liammclennan/JavaScript-Koans/blob/master/support/koans.js). I'm assuming it gets loaded before the tests because I am too lazy to run them myself :P. (It's in the `support` directory.)

In this file, there is a method called `equalTo` defined on all arrays:

```
Array.prototype.equalTo = function(compareTo) { ... }
```

So the answers to your questions:

1. Because the answer to the other question was wrong. Completely misguided. Etc.
2. Because the method is defined on `Array` rather than `Object`.

Seems a little bit underwhelming.

If you define a function like this on the prototype, it will be inherited by all arrays. Try defining something like that in the console and then evaluate `[].equalTo`. And then, for more fun, try something like:

```
for (x in []) console.log(x)
```

Since this method is defined on the prototype, the loop iterates over it as well. So the answer is to the test is probably `0, 1, 'equalTo'`. However, if you use the for loop with the `hasOwnProperty` check, it will naturally not iterate over the method.

This is really an object lesson about no using `for in` to iterate over arrays :). You never know what's going to sneak in... Coincidentally, this is why prototype.js fell out of favor despite actually being a nice framework.

Comment: But if you toss a [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/HasOwnProperty) into the mix you can get around the prototype problems.

Comment: @muistooshort: You still have problems if somebody adds some other property to your array: `a = []; a.alive = false;`. I think just using a normal `for` loop or--much better--an appropriate higher-order function (`forEach`, `map`, `filter`, `reduce`...etc) is the best approach.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you, using `for...in` for an array doesn't make much sense, it is more a matter of using `for...in` without including a `hasOwnProperty` check almost always being a mistake whether you should be using `for...in` or not.